# Pandas dataframe rolling, custom calulation, df.iloc ValueError

Tags: pandas, valueerror, rolling-computation, custom-function

How should I utilize the RangeIndex provided by pandas.DataFrame.rolling in custom_function?

Current implementation gives a ValueError.

At first x.index = RangeIndex(start=0, stop=2, step=1), and tmp_df correctly selects the first and second row in df (index 0 and 1). For the last x.index = RangeIndex(start=6, stop=8, step=1) it seems like iloc tries to select index 8 in df which is out of range (df has index 0 to 7).

Basically, what I want to do is to have the custom function to count consecutive numbers in the window. Given a positive values 1,0,1,1,1,0 in the window, the custom function should return 3 as there is a maximum of 3 consecutive 1s.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'open': [7, 5, 10, 11,6,13,17,12],
                   'close': [6, 6, 11, 10,7,15,18,10],
                   'positive': [0, 1, 1, 0,1,1,1,0]},
                 )

def custom_function(x,df):
    print("index:",x.index)
    tmp_df = df.iloc[x.index] # raises "ValueError: cannot set using a slice indexer with a different length than the value" when x.index = RangeIndex(start=6, stop=8, step=1) as df index goes from 0 to 7 only

    # do calulations on any column in tmp_df, get result
    result = 1 #dummyresult

    return result

intervals = range(2, 10)
for i in intervals:
    df['result_' + str(i)] = np.nan
    res = df.rolling(i).apply(custom_function, args=(df,), raw=False)
    df['result_' + str(i)][1:] = res

print(df)
```

Comment: your code raises an error at the `df['result_' + str(i)][1:] = res` line due to the `[1:]`, not where you commented it

Comment: @mcsoini thank you! I can't understand how I misinterpreted where the code failed, but I obviously did. Everything is good then, I can use custom_function to get the desired results